# Working with ArrayList<Double> in java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with an `ArrayList<Double>` function. I am trying to find out if the items within the sequence are all the same

e.g. allSame(<7, 7, 7>) returns `true`, and allSame(<2, -4, -7>) returns `false`

This is what I've written so far but its given me an error saying it cannot find symbol - method length() and also that an array is required. :(

```
    public boolean allSame(ArrayList<Double> s)
     {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
          if (s[i] == s[i+1])
          return true;          }
```

Comment: Why do we have 4 answers and 3 downvotes?  I feel like people that answer a question should make sure its not downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the s.size() issue, that method also isn't going to work logically the way you have it.

This should work:

```
public boolean allSame(ArrayList<Double> s) {
    for (int i=0; i<s.size() - 1; i++) {
        if ( s.get(i) != s.get(i+1) )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: oh thank you for that s.size(), I tried out your code but it gives the same error of "Array Required"  in the if loop part

Comment: There ya go. Think that ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your iteration gets outofbounds Exception

Do it like this

```
public static boolean allSame(List<Double> s) {

        for (int i=0; i < (s.size()-1); i++) {

           if (s.get(i) != s.get(i+1)){
              return false;          
           }

        }

        return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its is `size()` and not `length()`.

Please have a look at the docs once, [ArrayList.size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size())

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` doesn't have any method called `length()`. To access the size of `ArrayList` you need to use to `size()` method.

```
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to using s.size(), s.length does not apply to List.